# Crash on Android 10 (InflateException in layout/abc_screen_simple line #17)

Tags: android, androidx, android-10.0, calligraphy

My application works fine from Android 4.3 until Android 9 Pie, but my application doesn't work on Android 10 (Q API 29) and crashes. This is my logcat - why this is happening?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
     ComponentInfo{ir.mahdi.circulars/ir.mahdi.circulars.MainActivity}: 
     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 
     in ir.mahdi.circulars:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 
     in ir.mahdi.circulars:layout/abc_screen_simple: 
         Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
```

and this is my mainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

update

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0' }
```

Comment: use this lib com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01 insted of com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0

Comment: @MilanPansuriya not work

Comment: Please, share your whole error log... Usually, the real reason in these cases are mentioned at the end of the crash trace

Comment: @W0rmH0le i found problem, it came from calligraphy library so i fixed it by removing it

Comment: @git, any other way rather than removing `Calligraphy`? I couldn't find a solution for the issue but find this library handy for fonts, any idea?

Comment: For me, this is happening with, more or less, the same gradle config but I can't understand why this runs in devices with android P but doesn't works in devices with android Q...

Comment: My project does not use **Calligraphy** but I still face this exact issue on Android 10, anyone face the same issue with me? I tried to add calligraphy3:3.1.1 and viewpump:2.0.3 but it still happen.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Update `Calligraphy` to newest version to solve this problem:
Link: https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy/issues/35

More specifically, both Calligraphy **and** ViewPump need to be updated:

```
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
```

Migrating from Calligraphy 2 to 3 requires some code changes; see examples in [Calligraphy 3 README](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy).

Comment: Update: actually it is quite trivial to update to Calligraphy 3; the code snippets in the [README](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy) make it straightforward. But thing is, at least in our case **the Calligraphy update didn't help**: still getting InflateException with `layout/abc_screen_simple` after that.

Comment: @Jonik hmm.. very strange. Maybe some standalone modules in your app still have old dependencies to Calligraphy? 
Did you try to check transitive dependencies in gradle, maybe you'll see something strange?

Comment: @KonstantinKuznetsov: Thanks a lot! I checked `:app:dependencies` and saw that calligraphy3:3.1.1 was depending on viewpump:1.0.0. That was because in our build files we only had explicit dependency on Calligraphy. Adding viewpump:2.0.3 explicitly fixes this!

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the missing info into the answer.

Answer (score 67):

You need to update calligraphy version and change code according to new version

You need to change repository in dependencies from

```
implementation "uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:$caligraphyVersion"
```

to

```
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
```

You need to change usage of import from

```
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
```

to

```
import io.github.inflationx.calligraphy3.CalligraphyConfig;
```

Calligraphy config from

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
               .setDefaultFontPath(getResources().getString(R.string.bariol))
               .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build())) 
                .build());
```

to

```
ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
            .addInterceptor(new CalligraphyInterceptor(
                    new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            
            .setDefaultFontPath(getResources().getString(R.string.bariol))
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()))
            .build());
```

I used font bariol you can change it to yours.

& newbase to

```
super.attachBaseContext(ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
```

Comment: Thanks @Nafees Khabir very clear solution.

Comment: Thanks @Nafees Khabir very clear solution you really saved me more than you can think

Comment: @ SHahi SHiva , @Mosa I faced this issue so shared the solution here

Comment: thank you again then , really helped, tried so much solutions but with no chances, hope your life be easier  like what you made for my day :)

Answer (score 20):

```
 Please follow this below steps.
 1. First of all check build.gradle(:app) file

 2. If you are using  this below library:
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

 3. Update this " implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0' " library with this below library.

    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'

 4. In project where You use this below code :
    @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
            super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
        }
    
 5. Update it with this below code:
    
       @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
            super.attachBaseContext(ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
        }
```

Comment: This solution was explained properly and it solved the issue

Answer (score 9):

Definitively your problem is the Calligraphy library, I've got the same problem and there are 2 ways to solve it:

1. Go back to target version 28, and wait a possible update of the
   Calligraphy library. 2
2. Remove the library

**About the exception:**

The exception error in Calligraphy comes from the use of the reflection in the library. See the last line of this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example, PID: 8220
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.example:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in com.example/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.example/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Android in your documentation explain that some reflection methods (non-SDK interfaces) are restricted in the API 29 platform.

> Reflection via Class.getDeclaredField() or Class.getField() --------> NoSuchFieldException thrown
>
> Reflection via Class.getDeclaredMethod(), Class.getMethod() ----> NoSuchMethodException thrown.
>
> Reflection via Class.getDeclaredFields(), Class.getFields() --------> Non-SDK members not in results.
>
> Reflection via Class.getDeclaredMethods(), Class.getMethods() -> Non-SDK members not in results

[Source: Restrictions on non-SDK interfaces](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#results-of-keeping-non-sdk)

Comment: In all likelihood, Calligraphy dependency has been added in a project for a reason. No need to remove it; updating to Calligraphy 3 also fixes the InflateException issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57462616/56285

Answer (score 8):

if you are using calligraphy so you should migrate to calligraphy3 :
https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy

```
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
```

Answer (score 4):

Migrate from [chrisjenx/Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)
to [InflationX/Calligraphy](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy)
and update `Calligraphy` to newest version

Answer (score 2):

You can change buildTools version and sdk version from 29 to 28

```
    targetSdk = 28
    compileSdk = 28
    buildTools = '28.0.3'
```

Comment: This is a workaround, but at some point you'll want to update `targetSdk` to 29 in any case, and you'll need to properly deal with the issue.

Comment: Only targetSdk must be 28, compileSdk and buildTools can be 29, but this is temporarily solution

Answer (score 2):

This dependency `implementation 'com.ice.restring:restring:1.0.0'` also causes this crash **if** **targetSdkVersion** equals to **29** or higher,

so if you have this dependency (`implementation 'com.ice.restring:restring:1.0.0'`) in your gradle you can solve this problem by **removing it** or using another lib that work with `targetSdkVersion 29`

Answer (score 1):

When faced with this issue, just update the calligraphy and viewpump in your app gradle to the latest version. Presently, the current version is:
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'

Answer (score 1):

Update your **calligraphy** import in your **build.gradle(:app)** file with this **below**

implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'

implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'

and use **ViewPumpContextWrapper** instead of **CalligraphyContextWrapper**