# shut down app after changing targetSDK to 29 in android studio

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-source, google-play-console

```
compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 29
    ...
}
```

According to the Play Console, the new app will change to SDK 29 from August and cannot be uploaded unless updated from November. The app ended abnormally after changing the target SDK to 29. The log is:

> W/abc.def: Accessing hidden field
> Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;->mConstructorArgs: [Ljava/lang/Object;
> (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied)
>
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: net.abc.def, PID: 28318
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.abc.def/net.abc.def.ui.SplashActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in
> net.abc.def:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in
> net.abc.def:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class
> android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout

I guess this is because I am using a non-SDK interface. Because Google explains as follows

> ```
> Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;->mConstructorArgs:[Ljava/lang/Object;
> ```
>
> #No public alternative. Developers should never access this field directly.

Is the abnormal termination due to a non-sdk interface? So how do you solve it? Many LayoutInflaters are used in the my code.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue..did you found any solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you were not touching mConstructorArgs in your source-code then try searching if any of your libraries was accessing that field.

In my case the culprit was the old version of Calligraphy library.
[image]

[Crash on calligraphy library by chris Jenx for Android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495384/crash-on-calligraphy-library-by-chris-jenx-for-android-q)