# Xamarin.Android cant compile using proguard

Tags: xamarin.android, proguard

I have a project that is working perfectly in any version below api 29.

When i try to run in a Android 10 device the app crashes after show the splash screen. One of the solutions that i found was to use proguard with a custom configuration:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

Now i trying to compile using proguard but i got an error.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.DX.targets(5,5): Error MSB6006: "java" foi encerrado com o código 1. (MSB6006) (Garcom)

...
Destino "_CompileToDalvik" no arquivo "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.DX.targets":
  Compilação de destino "_CompileToDalvik" concluída.
  O arquivo de saída "obj/Release/stamp/_CompileToDalvik.stamp" não existe.
  Tarefa "MakeDir"
  Tarefa em execução pronta "MakeDir".
  Usando a tarefa "Proguard" do assembly "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
  Tarefa "Proguard"
    Variáveis de Ambiente passadas para a ferramenta:
      PROGUARD_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/proguard
    /Users/osdinformatica/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25/bin/java -jar /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/proguard/lib/proguard.jar -include '/Users/osdinformatica/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx//tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt' -include 'obj/Release/proguard/proguard_xamarin.cfg' -include 'obj/Release/proguard/proguard_project_references.cfg' -include 'obj/Release/proguard/proguard_project_primary.cfg' -include 'proguard.cfg' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime.1.1.1.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel.1.1.1.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable.28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout.28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.28.0.0.3/build/monoandroid90/../../proguard/monoandroid90/proguard.txt' -injars "'obj/Release/android/bin/classes/../classes.zip'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v9.0/mono.android.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/java_runtime.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Jetbrains.Annotations.13.0.0.1/build/monoandroid90/../../jar/org.jetbrains.annotations.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'/Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom - teste android 11/Garcom/trunk/packages/Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.1.3.50.1/build/monoandroid90/../../jar/org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/11/jl/okio.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/10/jl/okhttp.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/21/jl/com.android.support.support-annotations.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/23/jl/com.android.support.collections.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/15/jl/android.arch.lifecycle.common.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/12/jl/picasso-2.5.2.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/13/jl/android.arch.core.common.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/32/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/35/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/34/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/33/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/20/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/18/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/27/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/9/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/0/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/29/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/16/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/45/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/28/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/17/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/1/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/19/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/26/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/44/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/43/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/38/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/36/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/31/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/30/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/37/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/39/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/46/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/41/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/48/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/24/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/4/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/40/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/47/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/2/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/5/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/14/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/22/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/25/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)" -libraryjars '/Users/osdinformatica/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-30/android.jar' -outjars obj/Release/proguard/__proguard_output__.jar -optimizations !code/allocation/variable 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/osdinformatica/XamarinForms/Garcom (Is a directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at proguard.FileWordReader.<init>(FileWordReader.java:39)
        at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseIncludeArgument(ConfigurationParser.java:279)
        at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:150)
        at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:586)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.DX.targets(32,5): error MSB6006: "java" foi encerrado com o código 1.
  Tarefa em execução pronta "Proguard" -- FALHA.
```

proguard.cfg build action is set to ProguardConfiguration. I have already tried:

- update proguard
- set Java Max Heap Size to 1G
- enable multidex

None of this worked.

Comment: When you run you application in Android 10 device, it crashed, Is that debug or release process? You can test it in the emulator, check th logcat, if have some execptions.

Comment: debug and release didnt work. when i don't use proguard i have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63584150/xamarin-android-crash-only-on-android-10/64024601#64024601