# My App not work on targetSdkVersion 30 , how i can fix this problem?

Tags: android, targetsdkversion

I want upload my app to google app and can't upload it in targetSdkVersion 29 or lower.
Everything works fine if I have targetSdkVersion 29 or lower , But After I changed target sdk to Android 11: targetSdkVersion 30 this error is show :

```
    Process: com.mirasoft.st, PID: 29360
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mirasoft.st/com.mirasoft.st.splash.SplashScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mirasoft.st:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mirasoft.st:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3846)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mirasoft.st:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mirasoft.st:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.mirasoft.st:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.ReflectionUtils.getValue(ReflectionUtils.java:29)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:203)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:237)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:929)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:703)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.mirasoft.st.splash.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Please any help

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495384/crash-on-calligraphy-library-by-chris-jenx-for-android-q

Comment: but i don't use this library

Comment: Looks like one of your layouts is pulling it in: `at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater`.

Comment: I have put this implementation but still the same problem

Comment: NullPointerException

Comment: i know the error is NullPointerException but how i can fix it ?