# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in layout/abc_screen_toolbar:

Tags: android, androidx

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.acadamis.vidyaspoorthiteacher:layout/abc_screen_toolbar: Binary XML file line #17 in com.acadamis.vidyaspoorthiteacher:layout/abc_screen_toolbar: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.acadamis.vidyaspoorthiteacher:layout/abc_screen_toolbar: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout

AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
```

** It's working up to API 28, but not for API 29

Comment: what is at line 17 in `layout/abc_screen_toolbar`? paste whole xml view

Comment: got the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524914/crash-on-android-10-inflateexception-in-layout-abc-screen-simple-line-17

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crash on Android 10 (InflateException in layout/abc\_screen\_simple line #17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524914/crash-on-android-10-inflateexception-in-layout-abc-screen-simple-line-17)

Answer (score 3):

This problem happens when using calligraphy library.

```
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
```

Solution:

Replace new calligraphy library

```
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
```

Change the calligraphy initial code

```
ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
            .addInterceptor(new CalligraphyInterceptor(
                    new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("1.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()))
            .build());
```

And change wrapper

```
super.attachBaseContext(ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
```