# Can't upgrade compileSdkVersion 28 to 29 because of dependencies issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, groovy

My app was created many years ago. Maybe 2016. Now I make some changes to my app. But when I tried to publish my app to my play console, it told me to upgrade the compileSdkVersion and target SDK version to 29. I change to version 28 to 29 and now there are lots of dependency issues like, could not resolve some dependencies, migrate to androidx, and lots more. I converted my app to androidx via android studio and upgraded all/some dependencies but it did not work and my app crashed. I searched all of those individual issues and implement those solutions but my app is still crashed. what can I do now? Can anyone help me to solve this? It is really needed for me. can anyone suggest to me any fix for this issue?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.4, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony"
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://swisscodemonkeys.github.io/appbrain-sdk/maven'
    }
    maven {
        name "Fyber's maven repo"
        url "https://fyber.bintray.com/maven"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "____________"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 25
        versionName "4.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [.......]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.2.1'
    implementation project(':SDKAndroid')
    implementation 'com.appbrain:appbrain-sdk:+@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.vungle:vungle-android-sdk:5.3.2'
    implementation 'com.fyber:fyber-sdk:8.20.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev186-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is the error log:

```
13533-13533/<Package Name> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: <Package Name>, PID: 13533
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<Package Name>/<Package Name>.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.ReflectionUtils.getValue(ReflectionUtils.java:29)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:203)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:239)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:659)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:631)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at <Package Name>.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 2021-04-12 12:24:40.753 13533-13533/<Package Name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 2021-04-12 12:24:40.849 13533-13533/<Package Name> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<Package Name>/<Package Name>.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in <Package Name>:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.ReflectionUtils.getValue(ReflectionUtils.java:29)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:203)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:239)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:659)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:631)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at <Package Name>.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 2021-04-12 12:24:40.850 13533-13533/<Package Name> E/UncaughtException:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 2021-04-12 12:24:41.880 13533-13664/<Package Name> E/FirebaseCrash: Unable to parse Json response string to get message: No value for crashes
```

Comment: _I converted my app to androidx via android studio and upgraded all/some dependencies but it did not work and my app crashed._ You have to post logcat, so that we can check what's wrong with the migration.

Comment: I have added the error log. check this please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524914/crash-on-android-10-inflateexception-in-layout-abc-screen-simple-line-17/57232072

Comment: Check layout/abc_screen_simple file line number 17. it is showing error while inflating. There may be multiple such errors. You can debug it one by one and rectify it. You need to manually change some layout declaration code while  Migrating to AndroidX

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy/issues/35).Update **Calligraphy** to newest version: `implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'`

Comment: By upgrading the `calligraphy` package, it solved my issue. thanks, man. thanks a lot.