# Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout in Android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When Run the app in android 10. Its works properly, If adding support for android 11. It does not work. And before Was 28/android 9. then updated 30/android 11

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.folder, PID: 17183
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ABCActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.app.folder:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in com.app.folder:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
```

Gradle. also, the latest version was added.

```
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
```

Comment: are you using implementation "uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:$caligraphyVersion" this library??

Comment: Yes. I used it in my app. and thanks for the suggestion. I got the error. the new version of the library does not work in android 11.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63299326/9961828